# React warns about missing key on anonymous div wrapper with key'ed children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Given this code, React throws a warning that there's no unique key specified on the wrapping `div`, although it shouldn't be needed as all child components have keys specified.

```
class exampleComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(({uniqueId, xData}) => {
          const bar = xData.map(({id}) => (
            <X key={id}/>
          ));

          const foo = <foo key={uniqueId}/>;

          return (
            <div> { /* No key in here, as it's not needed. Throws a warning */}
              {foo}
              {bar}
            </div>
          );

        });
        }
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it needs a `key=` for the topmost child. Move the `key={uniqueId}` from `<foo>` to `<div>` I guess.

Comment: do you render multiple `exampleComponent`s?

Comment: @kinbiko No only one.

Comment: @Iso This is from the docs: `The key should always be supplied directly to the components in the array, not to the container HTML child of each component in the array:`

Comment: @Iso, yes, that works. But why?

Comment: @TobiasMühl re-read the docs: they explicitely require you to specify `key=` on the topmost child, not on the children. “Components in the array” here applies to your `div`, and the `container HTML child[ren] of each component` are `foo` and `bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `key` prop for `<foo />` component, you should set in to the parent `<div>`.

Working example:

```js
class exampleComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(({uniqueId, xData}) => {
          const bar = xData.map(({id}) => (
            <X key={id}/>
          ));

          return (
            <div key={uniqueId}>
              <foo />
              {bar}
            </div>
          );
        });
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```